# SyntaxHighlighter: How to turn off auto closing tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use the library syntaxhighlighter. if I give a code within pre tags it will be highlighted based on the file type(js,java).But if there is a opening tag in my given code it will be colsed automatically.
For example if there is a tag like `<code>` in my code, it will be automatically closed by `</code>`.I want to turn off auto closing. The link would be http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html

Comment: Could you add your own code? So far only a basic problem has been described, and this question is likely to be down voted.

Comment: I'm using the library syntax highlighter. If I give a code within pre tags It will be highlighted based on the file type(js,java). If there is line with tags it will be automatically closed. I want to make it stopped

Comment: Do you mean JS or Java?

Comment: Actually what it does is if I give a code they'll will highlight the key words ,comments etc. It could be any file like css,js,java etc.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that a syntax highlighter was responsible for auto closing tags. What editor are you using?

Comment: It doesn't depend on the editor.<pre class="brush: java;">I put my code here<pre> If there is an html tag in the java code it will closed the tag and display in the page which is not in my original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. That's definitely to do with JS, however that was not my scope, so I resolved it this way.

Convert `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`, and store it in your system.
Or if you are pulling records from file or DB to show up in browser and highlight the code snippets, you need to write a parser for that making same changes cited above.

I have also faced this problem in blogspot.